# How do you join on an aggregate function result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I am querying market minute data table with columns:

```
date, time, symbol, open, high, low, close
```

I would like to get the last column of each day. This is what I came up with:

```
select 
    a.[Date], a.Symbol, Max(a.[Time]) as max_time, b.[Close] 
from 
    MinuteData2016 as a
join 
    MinuteData2016 as b on a.[Date] = b.[Date] 
                        and a.Symbol = b.Symbol 
                        and b.Time = max_time 
where
    (a.Symbol = 'AAPL' or a.Symbol = 'ADBE')
    and (a.[Date]=20171102 or a.[Date]= 20171103 )
    and a.[Time] > 1600
group by 
    a.Symbol, a.[Date]
```

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'max_time'.

Comment: To clarify - you're trying to get the, per day, the symbol of the maximum time?

Comment: I'm looking to get the close, I'll edit the query. Sorry about that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to achieve this with a window function:

```
SELECT [date], [symbol], [time], [close]
FROM   (SELECT [date], [symbol], [time], [close],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date], [symbol]
                                  ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS rn
        FROM   MinuteData2016
        WHERE  [symbol] IN ('AAPL', 'ADBE') AND
               [Date] IN (20171102, 20171103) AND
               [time] > 1600) t
WHERE  t.rn = 1
```

Comment: My typical queries over this table take seconds. However this query is taking forever. It's been running for 7 minutes already? Do you know why that is?

Comment: @bkarj I completely ignored the `where` clause from your original question, sorry - I just edited it in. Try running with it, it should be considerably faster.

Comment: Ok now it takes less than a second. Thanks. Also you need [time] in the inner query otherwise outer doesn't know what that is.

Comment: @bkarj arg, copy-and-bug syndrome :-) Thanks for noticing - edited that in too